# Yishmael’s burial site

Tags: sources-mekorot

Are there any Torah sources that indicate where Yishmael (ben Avraham) is buried?
I have not found anything that mentions his place of burial

Answer (score -1):

Since the other nations of the world (even those close to us like Yishmael) are only spoken of when they relate to Bnei Yisrael, there is no need to mention where Yishmael is buried. The only need to reference that location would have been if the Bnai Yisrael had camped nearby or if a nevua had been made nearby and it was used as a reference. As a result, the Torah does not mention where Yishmael is buried. Apparently, Yitzchak did not attend his burial

Thus there are no Torah sources that say where he was buried.

Comment: So is your answer that there are no Torah sources on this? If so, you should state that explicitly in the answer as that seems to be the main point.

Comment: @Alex That is what I  said. I will add that specifically.

Comment: But why then do the midrashim / targumim speak of Esav's burial and not Yishmael's? How is his burial any more notable than Yishmael according to your reasoning?

Comment: @Dov That is because according to the medrash Eisav died when he was killed when he tried to prevent Yaakov from being buried at the Mearas Hamachpeila. Yishmael died and was buried on his own and was not involved with Yitzchak.